# Why does ToPagedList take half a minute on an empty IQueryable while the underlying SQL runs in just one second?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a piece of Entity-to-SQL code that composes an `IQueryable`, runs `ToPagedList()` on it and then passes the result into an MVC view.

`ToPagedList()` fails with a timeout running the SQL query. I extracted the generated SQL query (using `IQueryable.ToString()`) and ran it on the server - it runs in less than one second and the output is empty (which is correct).

So I have `ToPagedList()` running the query that would produce an empty result that runs half a minute and times out and I have the underlying SQL that runs in less than one second on the same server.

Since the SQL query output is empty I can't blame the delay on filtering, retrieval or whatever else in the EF.

What can cause a fast SQL query producing an empty output to run extremely slow from inside `ToPagedList()`?

**UPD**

This problem seems to have resolved on its own, so it looks like it was some temporary problem between the machine running the code and the SQL Server machine.

Comment: Did you try calling a SQL query directly from within the application with the same connection string? How long does it take in that case?

Comment: What does `(Enumerable.Empty<Object>().AsQueryable()).ToPagedList()` yield? The same latency?

Comment: Is this `ToPagedList` from MvcPager? (There are others who created extension methods with the same name.)

Comment: @Gert Arnold: That's from this thing: http://nuget.org/packages/PagedList

Comment: When you want to create a Page List, you generally need the total count at the very least. It might happen that this particular operation is a lot more costly than getting the data itself. In your case, I would try using an SQL Profiler and see what the `.ToPageList()` method actually attempts to execute, then try to do it myself and see if it still does it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run a TRACE on your SQL Server and look at the query that Entity is generating and then check its execution plan.

Most of the time the latest version of Entity does a pretty good job of creating a robust query but that doesn't mean that a well placed INDEX on the tables you are hitting would speed things up significantly.

Enjoy!